# Java, string difference algorithm

Tags: java, string, difference

I would like to get a feedback about the code below. Is there any way to improve it's performance? Maybe you know input values that might print bad output? The idea of the code is to count unique characters from s2 that are not listed in s1.
[Ideone.com URL.](http://ideone.com/K3URn6)

The code:

```
class Combine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s1 = bi.readLine();
        String s2 = bi.readLine();

        String usedCharacters = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            String c = Character.toString(s2.charAt(i));
            if(!usedCharacters.contains(c) && !s1.contains(c)) 
                usedCharacters += c;
        }

        System.out.println(usedCharacters.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, questions about optimizing existing working code are better suited for [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing an existing code that is not broken. Consider posting to codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fairly well optimized but you should probably check for null, as it will fail if you pass it null values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this performance is good enough and any improvements would not make a sensitive difference.

Comment: What about an input? Do you know any values which this code might fall with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to iterate over the larger or the smaller String (measure the time overhead) - that's where you can save some CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is relatively small (eg typed by a user on the console) then I see no performance problem with your solution (apart from the null checks as suggested by another answer).

If the input is large, eg redirected files on the command line of megabytes or more then I think your solution will yield O(n^2) run time performance as it iterates though s2 and the contains method call will also iterate across the whole string.

An alternative algorithm would be to sort the two input strings and then iterate across them to count the differences.   That would result in O(n log n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it but here's an idea:

```
class Combine {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s1 = bi.readLine();
    String s2 = bi.readLine();

    int count = 0;
    for(char c : new HashSet<Char>(s2.toCharArray())) {
     if(s1.contains(c)) count++
    }


    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}